# How to use ajax from react to express?

Tags: ajax, rest, axios, crud, redux-thunk

I am a newer about express with react.Now I have to solve one problem.
Until now I make the server side part by express and client side by react including  react router and redux, redux-thunk.When I send the post by axios to the express server then there will be error such below

### POST http://localhost:8080/api/users 404 (Not Found)

How can I accept CRUD request by redux-thunk in express?

The server side code is below

```
//app.js
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use('/api/users', userRouter);
app.use('/profile', profileRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});


//react redux-thunk side is
axios.post('/api/users', { name: 'LNI' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to provide `/public` instead of just use `public`.
Path generation is manage by the `path` module itself.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Express `POST` request is handle like this

```
app.post('/api/users', userRouter);
```

Read more about routing from official express documentation - https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html